# How can pyinstaller incorporate shared library?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

My python script imports a shared library (.so) which was generated by distutils.core from a C++ code. When I generate an executable using pyintaller, it prints out

```
The CococaAgg backend required PyObjC to be installed!
```

during building, and running the executable failed with

```
ImportError: No module named sysconfig
```

I believed this is due to .so importing, and not sure how to fix it in pyinstaller.

**Update:**

I installed PyObjC. The

```
The CococaAgg backend required PyObjC to be installed!
```

disappeared during building, but the

```
ImportError: No module named sysconfig
```

failure was still there during execution.